# Returning a specific JSON object using Express

Tags: json, node.js, express

So let's say I've got a massive JSON file, and the general structure is roughly like so:

```
{
   "apples": { complex object },
   "oranges": { complex object },
   "grapes": { complex object }
}
```

Is there some way to specifically target an object to return while using express? As in, say, if someone made a simple get request to my server, it'd return specifically the given object(s). I know the syntax and concept is completely wrong in this instance but for lack of a better way to say it, something like...

```
let testData = 'testdata.json';
app.get('/thing', res => {
   res.json(testData.oranges);
}
```

I know you can return the entire file, but that adds a good amount of loading time in this instance, and is impractical in this particular case.

Or, alternatively - would it be better to have node parse the JSON file and split it into an apples.json, oranges.json, etc files to use? Trying to understand A, the best practice for doing something like this, and B, the most effective way to translate this into a practical application for a medium sized project.

Any thoughts or advice along this line - even if it's a library recommendation - would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming the node process is not starting/stoping for each request, then requiring a JSON file (`const testData = require('./testdata.json');`) would load and parse it automatically on initial process startup (which would keep it in memory for the life of the process) which means that you could use your example as is to return parts of the file.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you make a POST request caring the payload of the specific '*thing*', and then returning an object based on that thing. Example:

```
let testData = {
   "apples": { complex object },
   "oranges": { complex object },
   "grapes": { complex object }
};
app.post('/route', (req, res) => {
   thing = req.body.thing;
   res.json(testData[thing]);
}
```

Comment: Will give that a shot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It doesn't need to be (and technically should not be) a POST request. This is a GET request and it should use a query parameter (e.g. `/route?part=thing`) for specifying the desired part of the object to return.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `GET` request for some data and essentially since the JSON file can be used as a key/value store to query for the desired response data.

Assuming the query parameter for specifying the desired key for the object to return is `part` then the following example would work:

```js
const testData = require('./testdata.json');

app.get('/thing', (req, res) => res.json(testdata[req.query.part]);
```

Querying for `/thing?part=apples` would return `testdata.apples` in the response.